# pytest json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: aws-lambda, pytest, boto3, amazon-sns, botocore

- List item

Hi,

I need to pytest this function

> ```
> def lambda_handler(event, context):
>  message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
> ```

But it failed by json error

```
def test_lambda_handler():
    event = {
    "Records": [
        {
            "Sns" : { "Message" : "test" }
        }
    ]
    }
    response = fw_init.lambda_handler( event,"")
```

```
JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
E           json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Function `loads()` deserializes JSON from string. You trying to decode "Message" field value as JSON.

`lambda_handler` function's first argument is a JSON-formatted string, according to AWS documentation.

You need to pass an serialized data to `lambda_handler` function:

```py
response = fw_init.lambda_handler(json.dumps(event) ,"")
```

In function `lambda_handler()` you need to deserialize data first, and then get field value:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = json.loads(event)
    message = data['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
```